# Filter on column values not in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do joins on two tables and filter on values that are not in my select statement.

The following query does not work.

```
select b.[[Product]].[Major Category]]] ,sum(a.BIC_ZCDP) from TEMP_FORECAST_ALL a
join OUT_Dimension_DP_Product b
on right(a.MATERIAL,10) = b.[[Product]].[10D]]]  
join OUT_Dimension_DP_Market c
on a.BIC_ZRMARKET =  c.[[Market]].[Market]]]
group by b.[[Product]].[Major Category]]]
having a.CALMONTH in ('201810','201811','201812') and c.[[Market]].[Region]]] = 'UK'
```

I get the following errors

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Column 'TEMP_FORECAST_ALL.CALMONTH' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Column 'TEMP_FORECAST_ALL.CALMONTH' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Column 'TEMP_FORECAST_ALL.CALMONTH' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Column 'OUT_Dimension_DP_Market.[Market].[Region]' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't want to add Region and CALMONTH in my group by clause.

Comment: Slight detour but something you should probably read. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` clause . . . :

```
select p.[[Product]].[Major Category]]], sum(a.BIC_ZCDP)
from TEMP_FORECAST_ALL a join 
     OUT_Dimension_DP_Product p
     on right(a.MATERIAL,10) = b.[[Product]].[10D]]] join
     OUT_Dimension_DP_Market m
     on a.BIC_ZRMARKET = m.[[Market]].[Market]]]
where a.CALMONTH in ('201810', '201811', '201812') and
      m.[[Market]].[Region]]] = 'UK'
group by p.[[Product]].[Major Category]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`having` is only for aggregates.  Since this is just simple comparisons, you want them in a `where` clause.  You'd use `having` if you were, for example, comparing to a `sum` or other aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

**Having** clause is used when we are using aggregate function, but here you are simply doing comparison so you have to go with **where** clause.

Answer (score 0):

A HAVING clause is used when you are filtering on aggregated data, i.e., if you wanted to filter on the results of the SUM statement, something like the following: 
`HAVING SUM(a.BIC_ZCDP) > 0`

However, for the purposes of your query, you simply need to switch the `HAVING` to `WHERE`, as so...

```
SELECT
    b.[[Product]].[Major Category]]],
    SUM(a.BIC_ZCDP) 

FROM
    TEMP_FORECAST_ALL a
        INNER JOIN OUT_Dimension_DP_Product b ON right(a.MATERIAL,10) = b.[[Product]].[10D]]]
        INNER JOIN OUT_Dimension_DP_Market c ON a.BIC_ZRMARKET =  c.[[Market]].[Market]]]

WHERE
    (a.CALMONTH IN ('201810','201811','201812')) AND (c.[[Market]].[Region]]] = 'UK')

GROUP BY
    b.[[Product]].[Major Category]]]
```

Again, a `HAVING` clause allows you to filter on fields that have been `AGGREGATED (SUM, MAX, MIN, etc.)`, while a `WHERE` clause allows you to filter on normal fields.